# What is wrong with my set up?

Tags: mining

Good day all,

Can someone please point me to the right direction. I am currently running a clayminer mining in ethermine and my average hashrate is 12mHs. I have a 6 GPU rig and my rog consists of:

6 Palit GTX 1070 jetstream 8Gb
MSI Z270 M7 for motherboard
i3 7100 kaby lake
Windows 10 64 bit

I have updated all the GPU drivers. I downloaded the MSI afterburner and tried to set my mem clock to +800 and still no good. Each gpu only has around 2 MHs what ever i do.

Please help me.

Comment: I have also upped the virtual memory to 16GB and have the nvidia latest driver.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to disable unused USB ports from the BIOS?

Try to disable the following and tell us the results please:

1. Disable unused USB ports.
2. Disable the sound card, as you're mainly mining, and won't be using sound.
3. Disable LPT or serial ports.

The idea is to save resources for those 6 slots to be up and running. Also try:

1. Update your BIOS to the latest version.
2. Then go to Settings>Advanced>PCI subsystem, and set "Above 4G Decoding" to enabled.

Comment: i tried to search for that 1.D version of BIOS, it seems that there is none, i have a BIOS click 5 installed, I have placed the PEG0, PEG1, PEG2 to Gen2 all then enabled Above 4G Decoding and the PCI latency to max.

Comment: try work with two GPU and see if all it work well

Comment: Hi @TahaBA, i have tried to disable unused ports from BIOS and updated to the latest BIOS o per the MSI website. Enabled those and still with the same issue of very low MHs. still around 1.5 per 1070 card. My NVIDIA version is 384.94 which is the latest.

Comment: use Claymore's Dual Ethereum+Decred_Siacoin_Lbry_Pascal AMD+NVIDIA GPU Miner v9.6 i seen someone on youtube used this software and all thing is good

Answer (score 0):

Update to windows 10 anniversary update or creators update or any latest update
It will solve that
I wasted many days t figure this out